# "CS1026: ) expected"

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ReportViewTable", cnx) 
  { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
```

When I try to open this page in the browser I am getting the

> CS1026: ) expected error

on this line, but I don't see where it's throwing the error. I have read that an `;` can cause this issue, but I don't have any of them.

I can help with any additional information needed, but I honestly don't know what question I need to ask. I am trying to google some answers on this, but most of them deal with an extra semicolon, which I don't have.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You'll probably find a bracket is missing on a line preceding the one shown.

Comment: when is says ") expected" look for a missing ')'...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is .NET 2.0, as your tags suggest, you cannot use the object initializer syntax. That wasn't added to the language until C# 3.0.

Thus, statements like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ReportViewTable", cnx) 
{ 
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 
};
```

Will need to be refactored to this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ReportViewTable", cnx);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Your `using`-statement can be refactored like so:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ReportViewTable", cnx))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: It's also a bad idea to use object initializer syntax in using blocks: http://ayende.com/blog/3810/avoid-object-initializers-the-using-statement

Comment: Thank you stormnet for the article link new to .net and i had used the origninal code block from an article on how to fill a datagrid. I dont understand object initializer syntax yet but it just went on my list of things to read about. And thank you stormenet for the answer worked great on to the next error! lol.

Answer (score 3):

You meant this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ReportViewTable", cnx)) { cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; }
```

Comment: I think he means that `CommandType` is a SqlCommand property and thus is usage of object Initializers syntactic sugar.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to use the object initializer syntax, so I'm not sure that your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Addition to `ioden` answers:

Breaking code in multiple lines,
then double click on error message in compile result should redirect to exact location

something like:

[image]

Comment: That is a great suggestion for debugging i am so used to the brutal sql errors that say your code is broken somewhere on this page but i am not telling you where that i didnt think to do this thank you for the suggestion.